# The controller for path '/' was not found or does not implement IController. in nopCommerce

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, nopcommerce

I am trying to call an action in HeaderLinks.cshtml razor view.

```
@Html.Action("SideMenu","Index")
```

SideMenuController is in a plugin that i installed on nopCommerce. All routing is good.

```
routes.MapRoute("Nop.Plugin.Other.SideMenu.Log", "sidemenu/index", new { controller = "SideMenu", action = "Index" }, new[] { "Nop.Plugin.Other.SideMenu.Controllers" });
```

But the view is showing an error - "The controller for path '/' was not found or does not implement IController."

I also tried with that...

```
@Html.Action("SideMenu","Index",new { area = "" })
```

Result is same. What is causing that and how can i get rid of it?

Comment: Does SideMenu derive from Controller or does it implement IController?

Comment: Controller. But I also tried Icontroller. That creates some errors in SideMenuController. I also tried with BaseNopController. It didn't help too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's

```
@Html.Action("Index","SideMenu",new { area = "" })
```

instead of

```
@Html.Action("SideMenu","Index",new { area = "" })
```