# .NET MVC throws 500 Server Error instead of 404 Not Found when cannot match a Controller path

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, exception

For some reason, when entering a dud URL to a file/directory/controller that does not exist, the following error is thrown:

> System.Web.HttpException
>       The controller for path '' was not found or does not implement IController
>       System.Web.Mvc.IController > GetControllerInstance(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext, System.Type)

IIS then follows the regular error handling and shows the page appropriate for a 500 Internal Server Error.  A 404 Not Found error handling logic should be followed.  **Another web application I am testing on DOES NOT throw this HttpException when it can't find a route, and returns 404 normally. So what triggeres this HttpException?**

**Why and how to follow a 404 route for this type of error instead of a 500?**  Below is the configuration of the error handling. No other code is handling errors. So why is the 500 error always shown. It's as if the default handling handles the 'can't find controller' exception as an error when in fact it's a not-found.

```
<system.webServer>
 <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace" defaultPath="/StaticErrors/Default.html" defaultResponseMode="ExecuteURL">
   <clear />
   <error statusCode="404" path="/mvcError/Http404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />    
   <error statusCode="500" path="/mvcError/Http500" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />     
 </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
<system.web>
 <customErrors defaultRedirect="/StaticErrors/Default.html" mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
   <error redirect="/mvcError/Http404" statusCode="404" />          
   <error redirect="/mvcError/Http500" statusCode="500" />         
 </customErrors>
</system.web>
```

Failed Request Trace shows this. Basically since no route is round, the HttpException is thrown, and the 500 route handling kicks in, instead of a 404.  I'm not doing anything to overide any normal default behaviour.  The `HandleErrorAttribute` is not being added either to the MVC filters.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps give us an example of a URL that produces the undesirable message.

Comment: Have you tried [This][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385714/deploying-website-500-internal-server-error

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it.  You should provide **all** your route maps.

Comment: @ErikPhilips The question does include the desired behavior. This isn't a why the code doesn't work query. It's a how does one reflect a route not found exception as a HTTP 404 instead of a HTTP 500... The routes are irrelevant, as I'm not hitting a route, hence the exception. This is simply using a new project in Visual Studio and the web.config changed to above.

Comment: The only way to change the error code is to catch the exception and change the http status code in **code**.  The web.config can't change http status codes to other status codes.

Comment: @ErikPhilips - do you think something in the question isn't clear?  Something inside MVC is changing the status code. I've now worked out this only happens using the latest version of MVC. Any exception just invokes the HTTP500 error instead of anything else. I'm not intercepting exceptions anywhere, just setting a custom error page. So in the example above, MVC selects to show the 500 error.

Comment: Does this happen when running in Visual Studio debugger?

Comment: @mxmissile It does follow the same behavior in IIS Express + Debugger as in a 'real' IIS environment. I need to track down what triggers the exception, as another working application does not do this.

Comment: could it be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22761883/the-controller-for-path-was-not-found-or-does-not-implement-icontroller-in ?

Answer (score 1):

You should add a filter controller to override some IIS custom error.

```
public class mvcErrorController : Controller
   {
    public ActionResult Http404()
    {
    Response.StatusCode = 404;
    Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true; 
    return View();
   }
}
```

Comment: I think it would be more helpful for the OP and further visitors, when you add some explaination to your intension.

Comment: I already have one code like this within the controller. And nothing else, trouble is, the Http500 method is the one that is always selected. So even throwing a HttpNotFoundException is literally treated by MVC as an unhandled exception and triggers the Http500 method. Strange!

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the

```
redirectMode="ResponseRewrite"
```

Option from you customErrors tag. Unfortunately, this does mean you will have a 302 before your 404, but it will fix your issue.

Alternatively, use ASPX pages for your error pages:

```
<customErrors defaultRedirect="/StaticErrors/Default.html" mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
   <error redirect="/StaticErrors/Http404.aspx" statusCode="404" />          
   <error redirect="/StaticErrors/Http500.aspx" statusCode="500" />         
</customErrors>
```

There is previous discussion on this issue on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/781861/customerrors-does-not-work-when-setting-redirectmode-responserewrite)